# Resolving conflicts: how to accept "their" changes automatically?

Tags: mercurial

When merging conflicting changes using `hg merge`, Mercurial inserts a set of markers into the files to be merged in my working copy like this:

```
<<<<<<< local
  version = 0.2
=======
  version = 0.1
>>>>>>> other
```

Then I manually edit all files marked as U from a list produced by `hg resolve --all -l` and then I tell mercurial I have resolved them by `hg resolve -m file1 file2 file3 ...`

In many situations I would like however accept either my-only or their-only changes on some conflicting files. I am thinking to create two simple sed/awk/whatever scripts named `accept-theirs.sh` and `accept-my.sh` or is there any "proper" way to do it?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use

```
hg resolve -t internal:other --all
```

to accept `theirs` and

```
hg resolve -t internal:local --all
```

to accept `yours`

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand what @djc means, but your solution works like a charm.

Comment: @psihodelia djc said pretty much the same, try `hg help merge-tools` (mergetools is an alias in latter versions)

Comment: As a side note, I aliased this: `[alias]
mine = resolve -t internal:local
theirs = resolve -t internal:other`

Comment: Those are three lines to add to one's own `.hgrc`, for the newbies: `[alias]`, then `mine = resolve -t internal:local`, then `theirs = resolve -t internal:other`. After that you can use `hg mine some_file.py` or `hg theirs -a` (for All)

Comment: As of https://phab.mercurial-scm.org/D4379, you may also need to include the `--re-merge` flag (e.g. `hg resolve -t internal:other --re-merge --all`)

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
hg merge --tool internal:other
```

See also `hg help merge-tools` for more information.

Comment: Or `resolve` for single files/redoing it. (Also, the quotes around `internal:other` are unnecessary.)